# Installing Ubuntu on Asus Zenbook Pro 14 (ux480fd)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, asus

I'm running into problems when trying to install Ubuntu on my Zenbook Pro 14. I want to dual boot and run both Windows and Ubuntu. So far, the steps I've taken are

- Shrink Windows partition
- Use Rufus to create a bootable Ubuntu stick (tried both 18.10 and 18.04.2)
- Turn off Secure Boot and Fast Boot in the BIOS. I've seen other answers advising to enable CSM, an option which I can't seem to find in my BIOS.
- Boot to the USB stick
- Here I've tried both "Trying Ubuntu" and running the installer from there, and running the installer directly from GRUB.
- Inside the installer, the trackpad only works sporadically (per reboot) and the whole system freezes regularly. For instance, it freezes after trying to power down.
- When everything works, I get to the step where I can choose where to install Ubuntu. Here, only the USB stick is visible. The SSD is no where to be seen.

Any advice? I'm out of ideas. I even tried updating BIOS to see if there would be more options, to no avail.

Comment: Additionally to the solution posted below you should try Ubuntu 19.10 - it solved my problems on the Asus Zenbook 14 (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1169200/327802)

Comment: I also had a lot of troubles trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS to this model.
Turns out updating the BIOS solved my issue. I followed the steps listed here https://jeroen.pro/2019/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-asus-zenbook-pro/ to handle an issue with the graphics card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linux to see the drive, you have to change the SATA configuration in the bios to AHCI (as opposed to Intel Optane super mega hyper whatever). I'm not sure how this affects windows seeing the partition though.

After installing a boot partition to dual-boot you have to add it in the bios as well. I found it a bit tricky, but managed to get it working in a few tries though I can't recall the details.

I find disabling and enabling the trackpad via the hardware key fn+f6 usually wakes it up. This also resolves any weird behavior that sometimes occur (not being able to move pointer beyond a few pixels etc.).

Comment: Same problem here (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1169200/327802), I filled a bug for the touchpad issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1849442