# Can't delete Ubuntu (merged parititons)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I messed up big time... I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10. First, I didn't know that my computer is on EFI so I followed a tutorial that couldn't work because of the EasyBCD problem. Then I wanted to follow the right one for EFI. And what happened is that I found the unallocated disk space where I installed Ubuntu previously and used EXTEND to add it to C disk but I forgot to delete the unallocated space. Ubuntu stayed installed without an option to boot but I now don't have a partition to delete so I can start freshly. Is there any way to save this now or do I need now to format even disk C? With the pen drive, I am still in Ubuntu. Maybe I can delete everything from here? I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: No reason to re-expand NTFS partition if you are reinstalling Ubuntu. In fact you just need to install the UEFI version of grub to convert a BIOS install on gpt to to UEFI install. You should only use Windows to resize NTFS partitions as it also needs chkdsk after a reboot. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried to reinstall it through the wizard, there was some grep error message. Anyway... I tried again, and I had the option Install alongside Windows. (I have no idea what happened to the unallocated space I added to C where I first installed Ubuntu. Anyway, I clicked on that and boom... Can't install because this computer is using Bitlocker. Went to Windows and did: manage-bde -status. Percentage Encrypted : 0.0%. Protection OFF. I'm not sure is this a problem because I messed up the first installation or something in Windows.

Comment: @oldfred, I managed to solve the BitLocker problem. It started a new installation. It says this: Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed. This is a fatal error.

Comment: Does NVMe drive have an ESP? And is Windows fast start up still on? Windows turns it on with updates, so even if you turned it off, it may be back on. If fast start up on, you have install issues and grub will not boot Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Disabled Fast start-up, disabled fast boot, disabled secure boot... I think I might be doing something wrong with the partitions. I created a 100GB partition in Disk Management (unallocated). From those 100GB, I create 200MB a flag as EFI. some 14GB swap, I even create 2GB as /boot and the rest as "/" (all ext4). Still the same error (Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1')

Comment: Do not use /boot, sometimes required for servers or LVM installs, but rarely now for standard Desktops. I do prefer smaller / (root) and then rest as /home or data partition(s). Default install now uses swap file. What brand/model system? Hve you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware?

Comment: I tried that as well. 20GB for / and 80 for /home. Something else is the problem. I have an 
ASUS ZenBook 14 UX425JA-WB711R. Win10. I haven't. I'll try to check that as well (SSD firmware and UEFI update). But I'm slowly giving up. It's been two full days.

Comment: A Asus keyboard issue. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ASUS-N-Key-Keyboard-Linux-5.11 may need newest kernel. Asus ZenBook Pro 14 UX480 Black screen acpi=off required, but 19.10 not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138820/black-screen-after-grub-selection-boot-from-usb-live & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170283/installation-of-nvdia-drivers-on-asus-zenbook-14-ux431fn-an001t