# Install Ubuntu when not able to install from USB

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I purchased a new computer an Asus X512FA-BI7A.  I had planned to install Ubuntu on it immediately.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible.  There seems to be absolutely no way to boot from a USB.  I've disabled Fast Book, disabled Secure Boot Control, but there is no CSM to enable.  So how can I install Ubuntu?

Comment: Check for how to boot from a usb in windows using you manufacturers instructions

Comment: Please check this: https://www.asus.com/lk/support/FAQ/1013017/

Comment: You really do not want CSM since Windows is UEFI.  CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. You may have to turn on a setting in UEFI, somewhere to allow USB boot or full USB compatibility. Possibly similar models: ASUS TUF FX504GM  Intel i7 8750H & nvidia 1060
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431147
Asus ZenBook Pro 14 UX480 Black screen acpi=off required, but 19.10 not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138820/black-screen-after-grub-selection-boot-from-usb-live

Comment: This is not really an Ubuntu-specific question. It is more about how to boot from USB in your laptop in general. You do not need to modify any secure boot settings prior to installation. All you should be doing is to reconfigure your boot priorities so that USB devices have higher priority than your disks. Also make sure you use a proper tool to create the USB installer in the first place so that it is bootable.

Comment: I already tried:  https://www.asus.com/lk/support/FAQ/1013017/  Did you see the note in red about *The Windows Operating System that supports Intel CoffeeLake and later processors is limited to Windows 10.
So the [Launch CSM] option is no longer in the BIOS Setup menu of Intel CoffeeLake processors.   Well I don't have the Launch CSM option!

Comment: Actually I don't really care if I can boot from USB, I just want to install Ubuntu!

Comment: Why insist CSM? Just create a UEFI bootable USB drive

Comment: I'm not insisting on CSM, I'm saying that I have no way to boot from USB.  I just want to install Ubuntu without booting from USB.

Comment: Well, to install Ubuntu or any operating system for that matter, you will need to boot from *some* installation media. If it’s not USB, it could be DVD drive or a second disk attached by SATA. But those methods suck, they require additional hardware, this is why everyone uses USB. For the sake of knowing how to configure your laptop, it’s better if you don’t give up on USB and understand why your USB stick isn’t booting. Try: 1-using another tool to create the installer, maybe Rufus. 2-using another USB drive, 3-using another USB port 4-updating your bios and resetting all settings to default.