# Why is my Ubuntu Bootable USB not logging me in?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, sd-card

Created a bootable Ubuntu USB from a Sandisk Ultra 32G 100MG(READ). 
I installed it from an SD card (3.0 USB) adapter with 64G and 170R 90W. The installation went smoothly.

My PC will boot onto it fine, when I reach the login screen and type in my password the Ubuntu loading screen comes up and then once it reaches the end of the loading screen my computer shuts off.

Will still boot into Windows fine, I am on an ASUS GL503G. Should I try a better quality USB? Or try an SD card? I am confused as is to why it will boot but it will not load.

Comment: Test your USB in a different machine.

Comment: Some of the reasons a bootable flash drive will not work are listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/1190765#1190765

Comment: Another Asus: Asus ZenBook Pro 14 UX480 Black screen acpi=off required, but 19.10 not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138820/black-screen-after-grub-selection-boot-from-usb-live
 Many systems need UEFI update and if SSD firmware update.  Does this system have nVidia? If so you may need nomodeset boot parameter until you install nVidia proprietary driver. Or can you boot recovery mode from grub menu and at terminal add nVidia driver? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers