# Impossible(?) to install ubuntu on ASUS Zenbook UX563F

Tags: asus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a brand new Asus Zenbook UX563F: 16G RAM, i7, 512G SSD.

Though it seems to run from a USB-stick it is impossible to install because it doesn't recognize the internal SSD disk.

Any tips ?

The problem I'm facing is that when the installer shows it's first setup choices (language and keyboard), it then detects the available disks and it only sees the stick from which it booted, but not the internal disk.

From a shell: `ls /dev/sd*` gives `/dev/sda` being the 4G stick as the only available device

... just tried FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso. Running `lsdev` from the install-shell gives 2 diskdevices:

- disk0 : being the 1G USB stick from which it booted
- disk1: the internal 512G SSD

but booting it, it also only shows the 1G stick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Is Windows installed? Do you want to keep it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Many new systems need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. And drives have to be set to AHCI, not Intel RST or RAID. But if using Windows first install AHCI drivers into Windows or it will not boot in AHCI mode.ASUS TUF FX504GM  Intel i7 8750H & nvidia 1060
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431147
Asus ZenBook Pro 14 UX480 Black screen acpi=off required, but 19.10 not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138820/black-screen-after-grub-selection-boot-from-usb-live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your SATA drive is configured as Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) in the Bios. If you change this to AHCI, Ubuntu will recognize your disk.

If you change this to AHCI, WIndows won't boot anymore. If you still want to use windows:

- boot windows
- via (admin) CMD:

  ```
  bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal
  ```
- reboot, enter BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd>), set SATA to AHCI, <kbd>F10</kbd> (save)
- continue booting windows safe mode
- Now Windows will automatically enable AHCI drivers.
- Remove previous safeboot setting:

  ```
  bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
  ```

Comment: stranding in step 4: after the reboot you can't get in because there is no network to verify ... trying to fix his

Comment: It does recognize the disk changing the setting to AHCI, so f**k windows ... and installed Ubuntu. For those wanting to keep Windows,  probably set 'safeboot networking' instead of minimal, at least figure out how to log in after changing that setting.